# Single page website with a onclick function(scroll)

Tags: javascript, function, scroll

How to make a function, when someone click on a nav link to scroll down to certian position, like home top 0px, content top 400px, footer top 100px etc...(Javascript or jquery

Comment: But why do you don't want to use HTML Anchor for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a call to one of the html elements with an ID associated with it.

For example: localhost:8000/your_page/#your_element which will scroll the screen to the location of the element on the page.